# Proving Dimensions Inequality: Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given a vector space $W$ and subspaces $V$, $V'$ and $V''$, such that 
$W = V\oplus V' = V\oplus V''$.

Prove:
$$\dim(V'\cap V'')\geq \dim(W) - 2\cdot \dim(V)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the direct sums, we have
\begin{align*}
\text{dim}(W)&=\text{dim}(V)+\text{dim}(V')\\
\text{dim}(W)&=\text{dim}(V)+\text{dim}(V'')
\end{align*}
Adding these, we get
$$2\,\text{dim}(W)=2\,\text{dim}(V)+\color{blue}{\text{dim}(V')+\text{dim}(V'')}.$$
Are you familiar with $\text{dim}(V'+V'')+\text{dim}(V' \cap V'')=\text{dim}(V')+\text{dim}(V'')$? (you may want to check out [the result here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637740/prove-that-dimuw-dimu-cap-w-dim-u-dim-w))

If yes, then we get,
\begin{align*}
2\,\text{dim}(W)& =2\,\text{dim}(V)+\color{blue}{\text{dim}(V'+V'')+\text{dim}(V' \cap V'')}
\end{align*}
Since $V'+V''$ is a subspace of $W$, therefore $\text{dim}(V'+V'') \leq \text{dim}(W)$. We get
\begin{align*}
2\,\text{dim}(W)& \leq 2\,\text{dim}(V)+\text{dim}(W)+\text{dim}(V' \cap V'')\\
\text{dim}(W)- 2\,\text{dim}(V)& \leq \text{dim}(V' \cap V'')\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot, very simple solutions

Comment: Simple solution with... mine upvoted :-)